# Trigger a model.get('transaction').rollback() from the deactivate hook in a route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I do a `get('transaction').rollback()` or `deleteRecord()` of the model in the `deactivate` route hook when the model is `isNew`? I can't figure out how to access the model from within the hook.

**app.js**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.route('new');
  })
});

App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.createRecord();
  },

  activate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('users').set('newUserCreate', true);
  },

  deactivate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('users').set('newUserCreate', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: not sure, but perhaps you can use this.currentModel https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L254

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code that does a `rollback()` on the model:

```
deactivate: function() {
  this.controllerFor('users').set('newUserCreate', false);
  if (this.currentModel.get('isNew')) {
    this.currentModel.get('transaction').rollback();
  }
```

Special thanks to @sly7_7 for solving this.

Comment: A `if (this.currentModel.get('isNew') && this.currentModel.get('isSaving') == false)` could be interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

Route objects know about their controllers. You should also be able to do this:

```js
deactivate: function() {
  var model = this.get('controller.content');
  if (model.get('isNew')) {
    model.deleteRecord();
  };
};
```